# Facebook Page Plugin set active tab

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-page

Is there a way to set the active tab for a facebook page plugin with multiple tabs ? (timeline,messages,events)

The docs don't mention anything about any endpoints and the html structure doesn't have any static id's or classes.

Something like `fb_page.setActiveTab('messages');` would be amazing but from what I've searched so far, there's nothing as such.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such method available.

The plugin however seems to respect the *order* in which you supply the tabs you want to show - the first one you mention is always the active one, placed on the very left (at least in LTR languages).

So you *could* replace the plugin instance with a new one, that has the tabs parameter filled with tab names in the “right” order, to kind-of achieve the effect. (Since that will switch the order of tabs the user sees, it might not be the best idea though, could get confusing.)

Also, this behavior does not seem to be documented - so it *might* stop working this way at any time.

Comment: yeah, that was one method i thought of but that would mean destroying and instantiating the plugin on every click and that seems unnecessary just for a tab switch.